# problems with SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS

Tags: python, django

In the process of allowing social authentication I don't want users to be able to create a new account when creating a new account with Facebook. However through implementation I discovered that when a user created an account with Facebook, it also created another account as well. I was under the impression that with this line of code:

> SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS = False

Is the boolean you need to "disable account creation"/block the creation of users. However it isn't working? Can anyone advise?

Answer:

Turns out that SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS is deprecated in django-social-auth and you have to use other means to block users create.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS is deprecated; remove the 'create_user' entry from the pipeline instead.

http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/v0.7.2/deprecated.html

Comment: Link is not working. Can you suggest another solution ?